Finding mean of distribution which gives specific percentage of results in specified interval
Let's assume that there is a known interval [a, b] and a normal distribution with a known standard deviation. How to find mean xbar of the distribution for which the interval [a, b] contains defined percentage P of results? So the only variable is mean of distribution. I can find its approximation with numeric method, but looking for analytic solution (general formula).
The assumption is that when the distribution is centered in the interval [a, b], there exists percentate greater or equal to defined percentage P.
There will be two solutions, at the same distance from the values ​​a and b.


There is no analytic solution.  Numerical solutions are fast, accurate, and reliable.

First, let's clear up some of the terminology. The variable $\bar X$ is the mean of a sample; the mean of the distribution is the fixed parameter $\mu$, for which we are aiming to find a point estimate using only $a$, $b$, $\sigma$, and $P$, the latter of which is the percentage of observations within the interval from a single sample of size $n$.
We can model each observed value as observations from a Bernoulli distribution, with the probability parameter represented by $p=\Phi((b-\mu)/\sigma)-\Phi((a-\mu)/\sigma)$ (note that little $p$ is the percentage of the distribution, different from $P$ the percentage from the sample). The sum of all of the $n$ observations within the region follows a binomial distribution which we will assign the variable $Y=nP$:
$$f_Y={n \choose y}p^y(1-p)^{n-y}={n \choose y}\left[\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]^{nP}\left[1-\left(\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)\right]^{n(1-P)}$$
We will use maximum likelihood estimation to try to find the estimator. The log likelihood function is
$$\ell(\mu\mid n,P,\sigma)=\log L=\\\log{n \choose y}+nP\log\left[\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]+n(1-P)\log\left[1-\left(\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right)\right]$$
We now take the derivative and set equal to zero to obtain the maximum.
$$\frac{\partial \ell}{\partial\mu}=\frac{nP\left[-\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)+\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]}{\left[\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]}+\frac{n(1-P)\left[\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]}{1-\left[\Phi\left(\frac{b-\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\mu}{\sigma}\right)\right]}:=0$$
Solving, we get $\Phi\left(\frac{b-\hat\mu}{\sigma}\right)-\Phi\left(\frac{a-\hat\mu}{\sigma}\right)=P$. (Perhaps not unexpectedly.) I'm not aware of a function that represents the proportion associated with the width of the standard normal distribution as a function of the distance of that width from the mean; if this function exists and is invertible we could take the inverse and therefore solve analytically for $\hat\mu$. We can observe that this function is a convolution of a uniform distribution with the normal distribution and therefore find its quasi-characteristic function (offset by a constant), but I don't believe this can provide any unique insight into the problem.
Hope this helps to some degree.

You could simply begin with the final paragraph starting "Solving, ...", because this is not a question about data: it's a question about Normal distributions. // It's worth noting that when $\hat\mu$ solves this equation, so does $a+b-\hat\mu,$ giving the second solution noted in the question.

@whuber The inclusion of $\bar X$ in the problem statement might have thrown me off, but rereading I think you are right.
